# Why the JS codes inside pre or code block executes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to show some JS codes in a page.I have tried using

```
<pre >
    <code>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                alert("Hello");
            });
        </script>
    </code>
</pre>
```

But if jQuery is loaded in the page then the I am getting an alert and the code is not being shown. How can i show this JS without executing the JS. I tried SyntaxHighLighter plugin and it's highlighting the code but still i am getting the alert.

What is the best way to show this JS code to users without executing them.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's typo or not, but your html code is not complete, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: That is not the cause of the issue, I've corrected it for now. For those interested, check the [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1fddec64-7b56-40d4-a0ed-c5e44880da6e/view-source) for the original text.

Comment: i was having problem inserting html in the editor.those Js codes are wrapped inside <pre><code></code></pre> block.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because neither `<pre>` nor `<code>` mean "Don't treat this as markup".

`<pre>` means "Render whitespace here"

`<code>` means "Present this (i.e. use an appropriate font, etc) in such a way that it informs the reader that it is a code sample".

If you want to use characters which have special meaning in HTML (such as `<`) then you still have to use entities to represent them.

- `&lt;` for `<`
- `&gt;` for `>`
- `&amp;` for `&`

You don't need to worry about `'` or `"` as you aren't inside an attribute value.

Comment: thnx. Then how can i accomplish what i want? how can i show the js code without executing it?

Comment: @joy, as quentin suggested, simply replace `< and >` with their entities

Answer (score 7):

Using `<script>` tags means that this is javascript to be executed.

Remove the `<script>` tags altogether:

```
<pre>
<code>
$(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
</code>
</pre>
```

Alternatively, encode the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;` so the `<script>` tags are rendered as text and not interpreted as script tags:

```
<pre>
<code>
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
$(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
&lt;/script&gt;
</code>
</pre>
```